# Django: efficient database search

Tags: database, django

I need an efficient way to search through my models to find a specific User, here's a list,

**User** - list of users, their names, etc. 
**Events** - table of events for all users, on when they're not available 
**Skills** - many-to-many relationship with the User, a User could have a lot of skills 
**Contracts** - many-to-one with User, a User could work on multiple contracts, each with a rating (if completed) 
... etc.

So I got a lot of tables linked to the User table. I need to search for a set of users fitting certain criteria; for example, he's available from next Thurs through Fri, has x/y/z skills, and has received an average 4 rating on all his completed contracts.

Is there some way to do this search efficiently while minimizing the # of times I hit the database? Sorry if this is a very newb question.

Thanks!

Comment: The only option I see is denormalization. Try, benchmark, choose the the most efficient.

Comment: So this is a trade-off between read speed and storage (also write speed) right? I think what I want to try is a 2-step search that hits the database twice but reduces the search set; first search for availability, then only search within those that are available, the other skill / rating / etc. criteria.

Comment: This isn't a theoretical problem, you need benchmarking. Sometimes several separate queries are faster than a complex one, sometimes not. DB hit number by itself shows nothing, 3 indexed lookups can be faster than 1 heavy query with joins and subqueries.

Comment: We will find it easier to comment on how to create a minimal set of queries if we can see your models, and what you have now to do this. Note that you can filter by queries which span relationships, which will definitely help reduce the number of database hits.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing the code, once it's done I'll post it here. Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: Are you searching for django haystack? http://haystacksearch.org/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this method will solve you issue for all 4 cases, but at least it should help you out in the first one - querying users data efficiently.

I usually find using `values` or `values_list` query function faster because it slims down the `SELECT` part of the actual SQL, and therefore you will get results faster. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) regarding this.

Also worth mentioning that starting with new dev version within `values` and `values_list` you can query any type of relationship, including many_to_one.

And finally you might find `in_bulk` also useful. If I do a complex query, you might try to query the ids first of some models using `values` or `values_list` and then use `in_bulk` to get the model instances faster. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) about that.